# Powershell script to check if Python is installed

Tags: python, powershell

I'm trying to check if Python is installed on a machine via a Powershell script.

My idea so far is to run the following:

```
$p = iex 'python -V'
```

If the command executes correctly (check the `Exitcode` on `$p` property), read the output and extract the version number.

However, I'm struggling to capture the output when executing the script in Powershell ISE. It's returning the following:

```
python : Python 2.7.11
At line:1 char:1
+ python -V
+ ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Python 2.7.11:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

Can someone point in the right direction?

Cheers,
Prabu

Comment: Check the value of the `$LASTEXITCODE` auto variable

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen That gives me a boolean value if the expression ran successfully, I believe. However, how do I extract the console output from the expression itself - so I can get the version number?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Version in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42407894/python-version-in-powershell)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that `python -V` outputs the version string to `stderr` and not `stdout`.

You can use a stream redirector to redirect the error into the standard output:

```
# redirect stderr into stdout
$p = &{python -V} 2>&1
# check if an ErrorRecord was returned
$version = if($p -is [System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord])
{
    # grab the version string from the error message
    $p.Exception.Message
}
else 
{
    # otherwise return as is
    $p
}
```

If you are certain that all the versions of python you have on your systems will behave this way, you can cut it down to:

```
$version = (&{python -V}).Exception.Message
```

Comment: Note that `$p -is [System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]` relies on Python only writing to stderr. If it writes to stdout as well, then `$p` is an array and `-is` fails. So a slight safer alternative is `$version = ($p | % gettype) -eq  [System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]`, then handling the cases of `$version` being non-null (has stderr output) and null (doesn't have stderr output)

Comment: That's the exact reason I wrote the first example as is :-)

Answer (score 0):

For python above **3.3**, a launcher was introduced which may be installed automatically or manually as part of [official installer](https://www.python.org/downloads/).

In modern situation, command `python -V` may give you error or nothing helpful (python may not even be presented in `PATH` by default), but launcher is supposed to be used both for checking installed python versions:

**`py -0p --list-paths`**

and to run scripts: `py -3.11 main.py` or simply `py main.py`

[Discussion](https://discuss.python.org/t/could-we-add-python-to-system-path-by-default/3067) which confirms.