# How does windows decide which python executable to use when multiple are defined in $env:path?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, powershell, executable

I have several python executables available from within a default powershell prompt as shown by `where.exe python`:

```
C:\Program Files\Inkscape\bin\python.exe
C:\Users\921479\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe
C:\Users\921479\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe
```

When I launch a python interpreter from this powershell prompt, it uses the first executable:

```
>>>python
Python 3.9.7 (default, Sep 22 2021, 08:12:47)  [GCC 10.3.0 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', 'C:\\Program Files\\Inkscape\\lib\\python39.zip', 'C:\\Program Files\\Inkscape\\lib\\python3.9', 'C:\\Program Files\\Inkscape\\lib\\python3.9\\lib-dynload', 'C:\\Users\\921479', 'C:\\Program Files\\Inkscape\\lib\\python3.9\\site-packages']
```

I don't want to remove `C:\Program Files\Inkscape\bin` from my windows path environment variable, since I use the `inkscape` command line tool for other purposes. However, I would prefer that powershell use the local installation of python 3.10 as my "default" python interpreter.

When I check the `$env:path` variable, it looks like the Inkscape folder is defined *after* the python 3.10 folder. So it looks like something else is used to resolve the python executable:

```
>>>$env:path
C:\Python310\Scripts\;C:\Python310\;C:\Python39\Scripts\;C:\Python39\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Users\921479\AppData\Local\SumatraPDF;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\texlive\2021\bin\win32;C:\Program Files (x86)\PDFtk Server\bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1;C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\clibs;C:\Program Files\Inkscape\bin;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Users\921479\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts\;C:\Users\921479\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\;C:\Users\921479\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\921479\.dotnet\tools
```

How does powershell/windows decide which `python` executable to use? How can I modify this?

Comment: What is your current directory (working directory)?

Comment: @ThomasWeller Just a temporary directory on my desktop. There are no python executables in it, if that's what you're asking..

Comment: Did you change the PATH variable, and if you did, did you reboot or restart all programs after that? What can be seen in [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) - which directories are searched for Python.exe?

Comment: I think I may have found the problem based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42407894/python-version-in-powershell/42409516

It looks like the order of entries in `PATH` is all that's used, and doing an `ls $env:path.split(';')[1]` revealed that there was no `python.exe` in `C:\Python310` to begin with. This is extremely strange, since I have installed python from python.org.

I've been using python for years and this has never happened before...

Comment: I know that your question is ultimately based on a misreading of your `$env:Path` entries, but given the question's generic title and the fact that Python is only incidental to the problem, it deserves its own answer, also for the request to selectively modify the lookup order for PowerShell (I've just added a solution to my answer). In short: Please consider accepting an answer or providing additional feedback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Thomas Weller's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69692166/45375) provides good general information.

As for using *direct invocation* of executables *by name only* (with or without including their filename extension) in **PowerShell**:

- **Executables specified by name only are looked for in the directories listed in `$env:Path`, *in order*, and the executable from the *first* matching directory is used.**

  - Note that PowerShell - unlike `cmd.exe` - by design, as a security feature, does *not* execute executables located in the *current* directory by name only and requires you to signal the intent to invoke such a program explicitly, by prefixing the name with `.\` (or by using a full path).
  - In other words: If a `python.exe` executable happens to be present in the *current* directory, submitting `python`:

    - in `cmd.exe` would execute *it*,
    - whereas PowerShell would *ignore it* and consult `$env:PATH` only.

This *is* consistent with your experience: even though your `$env:Path` variable has entries for `C:\Python310\` and `C:\Python39\` that precede `C:\Program Files\Inkscape\bin`, these do *not* contain a `python.exe` executable, as implied by your `where.exe` command's output, which shows that the only relevant directories are `C:\Program Files\Inkscape\bin`,
`C:\Users\921479\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310`, and
`C:\Users\921479\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps`, which *are* reflected in that order in your `$env:Path` value.

The **equivalent of your `where.exe` call in PowerShell** would be (except for PowerShell never listing any match in the *current* directory), using the [`Get-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-command) cmdlet:

```
Get-Command python -All
```

Omitting `-All` would show only the *effective* form of the command, i.e. the one that is actually used on invocation.

---

> How can I modify this?

Taking the **PowerShell perspective** again:
Depending on your needs, you have two options:

- You can selectively **modify `$env:PATH` for the current PowerShell session only**, which would **limit the modified lookup order to *that session* and *processes launched from it***. Independent processes (such as a separate `cmd.exe` session) would *not* be affected:

  ```
  # Simply *prepend* the desired directory to $env:Path
  $env:Path = 'C:\Users\921479\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310;' + $env:Path
  ```
- If you want to **limit the modified lookup order to *PowerShell code only*** - i.e., to `python` and `python.exe` calls submitted either *interactively* or from PowerShell *scripts or functions* - you can **define [*aliases*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Aliases)**.

  ```
   New-Alias python.exe C:\Users\921479\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe
   New-Alias python python.exe
  ```

In both cases, if you want to implement these modifications automatically, for all future PowerShell sessions, add the statements to your [`$PROFILE` file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Profiles).

Answer (score 2):

What Windows will execute is not trivial, since it might depend on the API used.

One of them is [CreateProcessW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw):

> 1. The directory from which the application loaded.
> 2. The current directory for the parent process.
> 3. The 32-bit Windows system directory. Use the GetSystemDirectory function to get the path of this directory.
> 4. The 16-bit Windows system directory. There is no function that obtains the path of this directory, but it is searched. The name of this directory is System.
> 5. The Windows directory. Use the GetWindowsDirectory function to get the path of this directory.
> 6. The directories that are listed in the PATH environment variable. Note that this function does not search the per-application path specified by the App Paths registry key. To include this per-application path in the search sequence, use the ShellExecute function.

Since Windows Vista, the environment variable %NoDefaultCurrentDirectoryInExePath% configures whether or not the current directory should be searched (Source: [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processenv/nf-processenv-needcurrentdirectoryforexepathw)).

Also: if you just run `python` without an extension, the environment variable %PathExt% is used to find executable extensions. (Source: [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/start)).

> The default value for the PATHEXT variable is: .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC

A great tool for troubleshooting such issues is [SysInternals Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon). Set a filter for "path contains python" (not python.exe) and you'll see the exact search order. It will report "NO SUCH FILE" for directories which do not contain a Python executable.

Also note: the [search order for DLLs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order) may be different.