# Running .exe to get String output is not saving to string variable

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

Forgive me, I am new to PowerShell in general.  I'm updating a build process that works on Linux (in bash) to one that will work on Windows in PowerShell.

My goal is to get the version of the game engine currently present on the build system.  The default build location is well-known, so we try to execute it and get the version, like so:

```bsh
$Version = & 'C:\Program Files\LOVE\love.exe' --version
```

When this executes, the `$Version` value is empty:

```bsh
Write-Output $Version
[no output]

$Version -Eq $True 
False
```

If I run my executable directly from the shell, I notice the line is not presented on a newline:

```bsh
PS C:\Users\robbm\Myproject\Mygame> $Version = & 'C:\Program Files\LOVE\love.exe' --version
PS C:\Users\robbm\Myproject\Mygame> LOVE 11.3 (Mysterious Mysteries)
```

This makes me suspect there is some strange output behavior with the executable in the first place.
Is this a problem with LÖVE's `--version` output, or am I misunderstanding something about redirecting outputs in PowerShell?  I've tried a few things to capture output, and `$Version` always seems to end up a nil value, such as:

```bsh
$Version = & '\\build\love\love.exe' '--version' | Out-String
Write-Output $Version
$Version = (& '\\build\love\love.exe' '--version' | Out-String)
Write-Output $Version
```

Help is appreciated.  As this works for other cmdlets, I'm inclined to believe it might be a function of LÖVE, but I'd appreciate thoughts as to how I could work with this anyway, or any method in which to capture the version it's clearly outputting to the screen when I execute it directly regardless.

EDIT:

LÖVE definitely does something different in regards to running on Windows.  Looking at [the version printing source](https://github.com/love2d/love/blob/fc4847c69d6c9ad7ed84501197427b23400ae1b4/src/love.cpp#L157), we are working with the aptly-named `LOVE_LEGENDARY_CONSOLE_IO_HACK` enabled on Windows, which appears to [open a new console entirely, perhaps in `cmd`](https://github.com/love2d/love/blob/fc4847c69d6c9ad7ed84501197427b23400ae1b4/src/modules/love/love.cpp#L497) and write out there.

Doing the suggestions of commenters, I tried doing the `.Exception.Message` method, but there is none when called like so:

```bsh
$Version = &('C:\Program Files\LOVE\love.exe' '--version').Exception.Message
```

So I'm still looking for ways to make this work within the confines of LÖVE hacking together some strange I/O stream.

EDIT2:

Another fun fact, redirection to a file similarly fails:

```bsh
PS> (&'C:\Program Files\LOVE\love.exe' '--version') 2>&1 > .\love.txt

PS> LOVE 11.3 (Mysterious Mysteries)

PS> cat .\love.txt
[empty]
```

So this looks to be overly hacky on behalf of LÖVE, not an issue with PowerShell.

Comment: I don't have the executable you describe, but this works fine for me with NodeJs - `$nodejs = & 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe' --version`. If you run `love.exe /?` or `love.exe /h` does it confirm the command line options in Windows?

Comment: It might be that [the executable prints to stderr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36953800/powershell-script-to-check-if-python-is-installed/36954394#36954394)

Comment: There is also that some exes print to host instead of output, whatever the command line terms are for that. For example older versions of 7zip could have the output captured and parsed, which was great for capturing and calculating progress, which I used for a few things, but later versions write directly to the console to display a live percentage that updates that line instead of printing on new lines, which cannot be put into a variable or run through foreach or anything.

Answer (score 2):

After reading your last edit, this probably won't help you, but may help others.

You could try to capture the output like this:

```bsh
function runCmdAndCaptureOutput(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string] $cmd
) {
    [string] $errOut
    [string] $stdOut
    # Deliberately dropped '$' from vars below. 
    Invoke-Expression $cmd -ErrorVariable errOut -OutVariable stdOut   
    if($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0) {
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "LASTEXITCODE: $LASTEXITCODE"
        throw $LASTEXITCODE
    } 
    return $stdOut
}

$exeCmd = "'C:\Program Files\LOVE\love.exe' --version"
$output = runCmdAndCaptureOutput -cmd $exeCmd
Write-Host $output
```